# Logic App trigger not being evaluated except on manual run?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-triggers

I followed Azure's [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow?WT.mc_id=thomasmaurer-blog-thmaure) to create a Logic App that should trigger on RSS updates and send me an email. When I hit "Run" the workflow works correctly and I get an email. But I don't get any emails except when I run it manually, even though there have been RSS updates.

If I look at the overview page, it says that the trigger has been evaluated 7 times and fired 3 times (the 3 times I ran it manually) even though I've created the logic app more than an hour ago and configured it to evaluate with a frequency of 1 minute. Also, the app is on "Enabled" status. (see image below)

Why is the trigger not being evaluated automatically?

EDIT: Since I posted this question, the app has made 2 evaluations automatically, but it looks like it does it every 30 minutes instead of every 1 minute. Maybe this is related to the fact that I have a student subscription?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the RSS connection is limited to 1 poll per 30 minutes according to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/rss/#known-issues-and-limitations

So that's why it only activates every 30 minutes.